# How to grep a whole line, pass to sed, and delete the line?

Tags: linux, sed, grep, find

The below command will find all occurances of a string and delete the contents of the files where this string is found.

```
find / -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec grep -i "stringtofind" -l {} \; -exec sed -i '/./d' {} \;
```

I have tried modifying it to just delete the lines where the string is found but can't get it to work.

E.g test file:

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah teststring
teststringblah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

It would delete lines 2 and 3 and leave the file as without gaps between lines:

```
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for `grep` here `sed -i '/teststring/Id' file` deletes all lines in `file` that contain `teststring` *(case-insensitive)* so just combined that with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -xdev -type f -exec sed -i '/teststring/Id' {} \;
```

`sed` demo:

```
$ cat file
blah blah blah
blah blah blah teststring
teststringblah blah blah
blah blah blah

$ sed '/teststring/Id' file
blah blah blah
blah blah blah
```

Comment: Doh, I had an extra escape character haha. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit a file in place with standard script tools.  You can create a new file, then replace the old one with the new:

```
#get a temporary filename
tmp_file_name=$(mktemp)
grep -v teststring $my_file_name > $tmp_file_name
mv $tmp_file_name $myfile_name
```

Comment: yes you can with ed or sed -i or you can code it with awk or.... Alsom you need to quote your variables. As written your script would fail for file name socntainging spaces or globbing characters.

Comment: Excellent point about quoting variables. Not sure how I missed sed -i since it's in the original problem. For some reason I avoid awk like the plague.

Comment: You should take another look at awk. It is THE most useful UNIX tool for manipulating text and will let you write the clearest, simplest, most easily maintainable and extensible programs.